# How to compile while gedit is open in gnome?

Tags: gnome, gedit

I am using gcc to compile c code that I am writing in gedit. My problem is that while my .c file is open in gedit, any command I type into my terminal just hangs until gedit is closed. Obviously it is quite cumbersome editing, saving, closing, running, reopening etc. I was wondering how I can have gedit open while compiling so I don't have to close it every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run gedit in background. Like

gedit yourfile &

Answer (score 2):

Are you launching gedit from that same terminal? This may be a stupid answer, but make sure you're launching gedit with an ampersand, i.e. using the command line `gedit &`. Without the `&`, that terminal window won't let you execute additional commands until gedit closes. With the `&`, gedit runs in the background. Gcc should have no problem compiling a file that's open in an editor. But remember that only the most recent saved version will be seen by gedit, so save your work before trying to compile.